# Execute conditional SQL statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to do something as simple as :

```
IF PAR1 = 'something' then

Select * from myTable

Else

Select * from myOtherTable

End;
```

Is this possible in Snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass table name conditionally using another variable.

```
set par1 = 'something';
set table_name = iff($par1 = 'something', 'myTable', 'myOtherTable');

select *
from table($table_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming that the tables have an equal number of columns with
> identical data types.

This is a way to do it using `UNION ALL` :

```
SET PAR1 = 'something';


SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE $PAR1 = 'something'
union all
SELECT * 
FROM myOtherTable
WHERE $PAR1 <> 'something'
```